# Bootstrap how to align horizontal in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment

How can i align the code below horizontal?

i want the logo in span 3 and 9 to be on the same row.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
<a id="logo" href="http://#">Logo</a>
</div>

<div class="span9">
<div class="inc-search">
<form action="http://#" method="get" class="search" onsubmit="#">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="search" />
<fieldset>
<input class="xlarge" type="text" name="sPattern"  id="query" value="#" />
<button  class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>
<div id="search-example"></div>
</form>
</div>

<div>or&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://#" class="btn btn-large">Post</a></div>
</div>
```

below is the image of my header

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJEoA.png

Comment: Question is not clear. They are already in same row man.. what exactly do you want? Logo uses first 3 columns and form uses rest 9 columns.

Comment: I want to align logo,input and the button horizontal its on the same row but not horizontally align.